# Compiler Insists on Referring to Non-existent Constructor

Tags: c++

What I'm trying to do is construct a `shadow` (or enemy) based on the attributes of the `Player`. I have two Shadow class constructors: one that takes a `player` and `boss` parameters and one that only takes a player parameter. If `boss` is true, the `shadow` will get better stats.

My code:

```
class Player
{
    
    public:
        typedef size_t pos;
    private:
        mutable pos lp;
        mutable pos sp;
        mutable pos exp;
        mutable pos lvl;

        std::string name;


    public:

        explicit Player(std::istream & is){is >> lp >> sp >> exp >> lvl >> name;}
        Player(const std::string & aName, pos aLp = 100, pos aSp = 100, pos aExp = 1, pos aLvl = 1): 
        name(aName), lp(aLp), sp(aSp), exp(aExp), lvl(aLvl) {}

};

class Shadow
{
public:
    using pos = size_t;
private:
    pos lvl;
    pos lp;
    bool boss;
public:
    static const pos sp = ULLONG_MAX;
    explicit Shadow(const Player & player): lvl(player.lvl + 5), lp(player.lp + 50) {}
    Shadow(const Player & player, bool boss);
    pos showLvl() const {return this->lvl;}
    pos showLp() const {return this->lp;}

};


Shadow::Shadow(const Player & player, bool boss)
{
    if(!boss)
        Shadow(player); // error here
    else
    {
        lvl = player.lvl + 10;
        lp = player.lp + 150;
    }

    int main()
    {Player Minato("Minato");
    Player Junpei("Junpei");
    Player Yukari("Yukari");
    Player Akihiko("Akihiko");

    Shadow blockGuard(Minato, false);
     return 0;}
```

The error I get: "no matching function for call to 'Shadow::Shadow()'."

The thing is that there's no Shadow::Shadow() constructor. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code

```
Shadow(player); // error here
```

doesn’t do what you think it does. It’s equivalent to the following code:

```
Shadow player;
```

That is: you’re attempting to declare a local object `player` of class `Shadow` and default-construct it. This fails due to the missing constructor.

You want to call a delegating constructor. For this, you need to use the *initialiser list*:

```
Shadow::Shadow(const Player & player, bool boss) : Shadow(player) {
    if (boss) {
        // boost stats
    }
}
```